# flow-typed libdef with namespaced import

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

Using [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) for flow libdefs, it seems that namespaced imports aren't processed against the relevant libdef.

I'm unsure of the technical name for these imports so I'm using the term "namespaced imports" to refer to imports that don't destructure the core lib, but import a single function from a path.

For example, the following is checked and fails as expected:

```
import { flow } from 'lodash';

flow('');
```

This fails because `flow` can only accept an array of `Func`.

Here's the same thing but using a namespaced import:

```
import flow from 'lodash/flow';

flow('');
```

Flow does not fail this code as expected.

Is there a way to get flow to work with this type of import?

Comment: You'd have to specify the type definitions for all of these yourself since the type definitions from flow-typed only appear to cover the main `lodash` module entry point.

Comment: How would you do that?